# Modifying Dojo Filtering Select Template

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I'm trying to modify Dojo's filtering select. As it is right now, it uses input html tag instead of select, option tags. As of now, how I'm trying to achieve this is inheriting whole FilteringSelect and supplying it with my own templateString.

```
var myFilteringSelect = declare([FilteringSelect], {
templateString: '' + 
        '<div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft" id="widget_${id}" role="${role}">' +
        '   <div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer"' +
        '       data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode, _popupStateNode" role="presentation">' +
        //'     <input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" type="image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAadEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAFBhaW50Lk5FVCB2My41LjEwMPRyoQAAAA1JREFUGFdj+P//PwMACPwC/ohfBuAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" tabIndex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" ${_buttonInputDisabled} />' +
        '       <input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" ' + '' /*'type="image"*/ + ' alt="" tabIndex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" ${_buttonInputDisabled} />' +
        '       <span class="dropDownText">&#9660;</span>' +
        '   </div>' +
        '   <div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer">' +
        '       <input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="&#935; " type="text" tabIndex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"/>' +
        '   </div>' +
        '   <div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer">' +
        '       <input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" ${!nameAttrSetting} type="text" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="${hasDownArrow}" />' +
        '   </div>' +
        '</div>',
```

However editing

```
<input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" ${!nameAttrSetting} type="text" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="${hasDownArrow}" />
```

to

```
<select class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" ${!nameAttrSetting} type="text" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="${hasDownArrow}" /></select>
```

doesn't seem to solve the problem, because no options tags are created.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Forget dijitReset and such, they are ancient fossils, as most of the dijit, too. If you want working widgets in dojo, implement yours.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it uses html tags instead of tags". I don't understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what happened there. What I meant: As it is right now, it uses html input tag instead of select, option tags.